# Github Desktop to Gitlab CE - send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: gitlab, raspberry-pi, gitlab-ce

I have i pi4 running gitlab ce and i upload do it using git and github desktop, since ive switched providers the initial commit is quite large around 14,000 files with a gitignore. From the log below you can see it going to file 10730 and then disconnecting. Im guessing it may be like a limit with bandwidth or something but im not sure.

log file(only including the end):

---

remote: Checking connectivity: 10310
remote: Checking connectivity: 10328
remote: Checking connectivity: 10346
remote: Checking connectivity: 10364
remote: Checking connectivity: 10376
remote: Checking connectivity: 10388
remote: Checking connectivity: 10406
remote: Checking connectivity: 10465
remote: Checking connectivity: 10517
remote: Checking connectivity: 10559
remote: Checking connectivity: 10627
remote: Checking connectivity: 10653
remote: Checking connectivity: 10683
remote: Checking connectivity: 10713
remote: Checking connectivity: 10730
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = The git server, Gitaly, is not available at this time. Please contact your administrator.
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

(The error was parsed as 4: The remote disconnected. Check your Internet connection and try again.)
2023-10-19T17:41:03.099Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune --recurse-submodules=on-demand origin (took 1.796s)
2023-10-19T17:41:04.109Z - info: [ui] Executing updateRemoteHEAD: git -c credential.helper= remote set-head -a origin (took 1.009s)
2023-10-19T17:46:15.853Z - info: [ui] [RepositoryIndicatorUpdater]: Refreshing sidebar indicators for 2 repositories took 10.8s of which 311.7s paused, total 322.5s